# What do the bars in "Games Won" mean?

Tags: overwatch

I've played 12 games, and won 5.  The game claims I have 3 wins.  The games I won were with Pharah, Widowmaker, Mccree, Reaper, and Hanzo.  *(Though it says I have 0 minutes played with Reaper and Hanzo, so apparently those games didn't get recorded...)*.  I haven't played any character twice yet.

Here is my games won statistic:

[image: Games Won]

I can guess the numbers mean number of wins... but what do the bars represent?

Comment: Huh. Don't know. Did you play the full game with the character each time? Maybe some kind of percentage of time played? Or relative scores? Do you remember if you did much better with Pharah than Torbjorn?

Comment: @DCShannon: That makes sense, I think I did switch, and the empty area in Widow/Mcree seem to match up with the other two.  However how does that work over the course of multiple games?

Comment: I think they represent the amount of time you played with each character, at least that's what I remember from the open beta.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments that you may have switched heroes during your games, it appears to be a percentage of each game played * 1 per each win.  So if you won four games where you played D.Va for 75% of each of the games and Mei for 25%, you would have the D.Va bar show 4*0.75 = 3 wins and Mei would show 4*0.25 = 1 win.

These bars obviously wouldn't show up as whole numbers most of the time if you switch heroes often during games as it is unlikely that you would end up with exact amounts of whole games played.  It seems to round numbers to the nearest whole, so each of those games that you won that you played the character for less than 50% of the time slightly fills up the bar but is labelled as "0 wins."

Answer (score 1):

I went and checked on my stats again, and the blue bars represent the percentage with regard to the highest stat that you have filtered by. If they are equal, such as in games won, it will show the percentage based on time played.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My bars do not match up at all.  In the above screenshot, Widowmaker and McCree were my most-played characters.

Comment: Are you sure you comparing between the correct game modes? A.I instead of quickmatch?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft edited, this seem to hold true for you?

Comment: @Dragonrage No, this answer still doesn't seem to be correct.  You say the bars in "Games Won" will equal the bars in one the other stats, but the size of Zarya's bar is different in every one of your pictures.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft for the Time Played stat, both Zarya and Junkrat are at 1 hour, however I have played more time with Zarya than Junkrat, so her bar is longer than Junkrat's. I had said before that they will equal bars in another picture, however I have since edited that to provide updated information. The bars are a representation of the percentage of whatever the highest score for the stat you are filtering by.